# Unexpected Results Using isdigit(x)

Tags: c

I am using the following code. I expect the output to be "Yes", but I instead get "No." I must be missing something very simple and fundamental.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 3;

    if (isdigit(n))
    {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("No\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isdigit` checks whether the character passed to it is a numeric character. Therefore, its argument should be `char` type or `int` type which is the code of a character.

Here, you are passing `3` to `isdigit`. In ASCII, `3` is the code of the character `ETX` (end of text) which is a non-numeric character. Therefore, `isdigit(3)` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit()` expects a character code, while you expect it to accept a plain number.
Those expectations do not mesh well.

Character literals:

- `'0'` ordinal 0x30 -- 48
- `'1'` ordinal 0x31 -- 49
- `'2'` ordinal 0x32 -- 50
- ... You get the drift

Answer (score 1):

'3' is not a digit, here, in the way `isdigit()` considers them. Change `int n = 3` to `int n = '3'`. If your system uses ASCII, for instance, `3` is the end of text marker, whereas `51`, equivalent to `'3'`, is the actual character three.

Answer (score 0):

`isdigit` expects a character. If the character passed is digit then it returns non zero. `3` is an ASCII value of non-printable character, i.e it doesn't represent a digit and that's why your `else` body gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

`man isdigit`:

```
These functions check whether  c,  which  must  have  the  value  of  an
unsigned  char or EOF, falls into a certain character class according to
the current locale.
```

3 is an integer, not a character. In fact, 3 is also the value of a character that is not a digit.

Comment: The point is, the passed integer number `3` does not fall into the character class _digit_ according to the current locale.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the implementation of function `isdigit`:**

```
int isdigit(char c)
{
    return '0' <= c && c <= '9';
}
```

In simple words, function `isdigit` takes a `char` argument as input:

- If the input represents a decimal digit in ASCII format, then the function returns 1.
- If the input does not represent a decimal digit in ASCII format, then the function returns 0.

When you call function `isdigit` with an `int` argument, the argument is first truncated to a `char`. That doesn't make any difference in your example, since 3 fits into a `char`, so no information is lost due to the truncation. However, since 3 does not represent any decimal digit in ASCII format, the return-value of `isdigit(3)` is 0.

**To summarize the above:**

- The return-value of `isdigit('0')` is 1.
- The return-value of `isdigit('1')` is 1.
- ...
- The return-value of `isdigit('9')` is 1.
- In all other cases, the-return value of `isdigit(...)` is 0.

---

Your mistake probably stems from the assumption that `'3' == 3`. If you want to check whether or not an `int` variable stores a single-decimal-digit value, then you can implement a slightly different function:

```
int isintdigit(int i)
{
    return 0 <= i && i <= 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string `"\03\t\nABCabc123"` is composed of 12 characters. The first 9 characters all return false when applied to the `isdigit()` function. The last 3 all return true;

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char data[] = "\03\t\nABCabc123";
    // data[0] = 3;
    char *ptr = data;
    while (*ptr) {
        printf("%4d --> %s\n", *ptr, isdigit((unsigned char)*ptr) ? "true" : "false");
        ptr++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```